# Webpack export not found in png image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, express, webpack

I'm trying to making a website under Webpack, ReactJS, Babel, Express and Sass, so far, all working perfectly, but when I'm trying to import an image like this:

```js
import { Logo } from './../../Logo.png';
```

And use it in an image like this:

```html
<img src={ Logo } alt="Logo" />
```

I'm getting this error:

```
./src/components/Header/Header.js 7:9-13
"export 'Logo' was not found in './../../Logo.png'
```

I've tried many solutions on the web but nothing solve my problem.
This is my webpack configuration:

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin],
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
            use: [{
                // loader: 'url-loader'
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash].[ext]'
                }
            }]
        }, {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }]
    }
};
```

And yeah, I'm sure this is the good path to the file.
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing the image without curly braces:

`import Logo from './../../Logo.png';`

Documentation from Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/

Documentation from create-react-app: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/